# How to identify the symbols in the symbol table are my 'application' functions

Tags: c++, c, elf, debug-symbols, intel-pin

I have an example C program `test.c` that defines three functions only: `main`, `fn1` and `fn2`:

```
void fn1(void){...}
void fn2(void){...}
int main(int argc, char** argv){...}
```

Compiling and then extracting the symbol table of this program (via `nm ./test`) gives a ton of symbols:

```
0000000000601030 B __bss_start
0000000000601030 b completed.8086
0000000000601020 D __data_start
0000000000601020 W data_start
0000000000400430 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000400420 T _dl_relocate_static_pie
00000000004004a0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000600e18 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000601028 D __dso_handle
0000000000600e20 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000601030 D _edata
0000000000601038 B _end
0000000000400724 T _fini
00000000004005d0 T fn1
00000000004004e0 T fn2
00000000004004d0 t frame_dummy
.... and so on
```

I can see `main`, `fn1` and `fn2` in the output, but is there any way to differentiate these from the other application symbols? Even only looking at the symbols in the text (code) section, there are 16 symbols. I understand in general what these symbols relate to, but I'd like some mechanism to identify them distinct from 'my own'.

The context of my question is Intel Pintools, where I can't find a way to filter my instrumentation pintool written in C++ to the routines within the `.text` section that I care about (i.e. the application functions). In my pintool, I want to do something like:

```
VOID Routine(RTN rtn, VOID *v)
{

  if(is_application_function(rtn)){
    // instrument this routine with some calls
  } else {
    // don't instrument
  }

}
```

How could I possibly implement the `is_application_function(RTN rtn)`? I can filter it to only my application (checking that the image type == shared) and the `.text` part (checking that the section name == `.text`), but after that I can't filter any further... Any ideas?

I wouldn't necessarily be against relatively hacky solutions. Are the additional symbols always constant meaning I could filter them out? Do the additional symbols always reside in a particular region of addresses? Is there a tool that I could run during initialisation, with results read into a white or black-list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way to differentiate these from the other application symbols?

No.

> I can't find a way to filter my instrumentation pintool written in C++ to the routines within the .text section that I care about

It's *your* application. Surely you can either use consistent naming, or collect a list of symbols you care about, and use that.

Comment: Thanks for answering! The end-goal of the pintool would be for others to use it with their own applications, so while the 'test' program is indeed mine, I can't enforce naming conventions etc. In this case I may just have to accept the overhead and instrument more than I want to!

Comment: @ricky116 You can either instrument more than you want to, or allow end-user to supply a file containing a list of symbols the end-user is interested in.

Comment: I'll check to see how much it really matters to instrument more, and go from there. Thanks for your help, I'll mark this as answered

Answer (score 0):

At least you can use function IMG_IsMainExecutable(img) to eliminate functions which are part of other libraries.

```
 VOID ImageLoad( IMG img, VOID *v )
   {
     string imgname=IMG_Name(img);
     if(IMG_IsMainExecutable(img))
      {
          //read the RTN list and instrument every rtn
       }
   }
```